# Not catching XMPPException when sent message using asmack

Tags: android, asmack

I am working in an android application to implement facebook chat and I have implemented it successfully using asmack libary. But when I tried to sent message when there is no internet connection XMPPException is not caught correctly. It shows Class file editor-source not found. I have downloaded my asmack libary from this [link](https://code.google.com/p/asmack/downloads/detail?name=asmack-issue15.jar&can=2&q=). Please look into my code and suggest me a solution.

Thanks.

```
  public Boolean sentMessage(String message, Long senderid) {
            ChatManager chatmanager = connection.getChatManager();
            Chat newChat = chatmanager.createChat("-" + senderid
                    + "@chat.facebook.com", new MessageListener() {

                @Override
                public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
                    System.out.println("Received message: " + message.getBody());

                }
            });

            try {
                newChat.sendMessage(message);
            } catch (XMPPException e) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: i am facing a problem in sending and receiving message on android device from xmpp server using asmack, Can you come over this [link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68853/trying-to-learn) to help me, Thanks